# Connecting to a MySQL database using DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database.

I found this script and I am trying to use it on my PC and web host, but it doesn't show any output.

Please have a look at this code. I am running perl at xampp.

```
#!C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver   = "localhost"; 
my $database = "data";
my $dsn      = "DBI:$driver:database = $database";
my $userid   = "root";
my $password = "";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I am using the same database with PHP.

Comment: What kind of output would you expect to see? You're only printing a header, which is invisible!

Comment: Anything in the webserver log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it doesn't show any output.

Judging by the CGI header you're displaying, I assume that you're running this as a CGI program. In which case, it's no surprised that you're not seeing any output - you're not sending any output.

If you ran it as a command line program (and it's often a good idea to get stuff working on the command line before leaping into CGI programming), then you would see the "Content-Type" header. Alternatively, you could add some output to your program and see if that appears in your browser. Something simple like:

```
print 'It works!';
```

I'd also like to add, that CGI looks rather outdated these days and there are far better (by which I mean easier and more powerful) ways to write web applications with Perl. You might like to read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) to get an idea of what is available.

**Update:**

I've just seen this question asked on Facebook (please don't cross-post without telling people) and I've noticed that your `$driver` variable is wrong. If you're connecting to MySQL, then `$driver` should be "mysql" (so that DBI loads "DBD::mysql").

Answer (score 4):

A DSN for the MySQL driver looks like this

```
DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port
```

where the `host` and `port` fields are optional. (The `database` is also optional, but you don't want to leave that out.) There are several more esoteric options too, but they're irrelevant here

But you're supplying

```
DBI:localhost:database = data
```

Which doesn't even specify a MySQL connection, so I'm not surprised if it doesn't work! I don't know whether the spaces are legal, but I would leave them out to keep in line with the documentation.

You should change that statement to

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$driver"
```

You may remove `;host=$driver` if you wish (why have you called the host name "driver"?) as `localhost` is the default. A DSN that specifies just a database name and uses the default for all the other fields may be contracted to just

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database"
```

It may be easier to just write `print` statements at first to generate some output. You will want to print a MIME content type header of `text/plain` instead of `text/html`. Try `print "$DBI::errstr\n"` for now instead of `die`, as the latter writes to stderr which won't appear in your browser

Answer (score -1):

you could add:

```
if ($dbh) {
 print 'connect ok';
} else {
 print 'connect failed';
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. I stopped using die in recent years. I prefer reacting to errors instead of just alerting them.